SciPy nonlinear constraints in case of increasing values
I'm having trouble with global optimisation for a function that has specific constraints on the values. Let me explain the situation.
We have a function F(x1, x2,..., xn, a, b), and our goal is to find its global minimum. We also have constraints from physics: x[i] <= x[i+1] for all values of x. All values in x[i] and a,b have boundaries (0,1).
How can I set up the correct nonlinear constraint for x in SciPy?
I've already tried this option:
def con(x):
    out = np.ones(N)

    for i in range(N-1):
        if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
            out[i:] = -1
            return out
        else:
            out[i] = 1

    if x[N - 1] < x[N - 2]: 
        out[N - 1] = -1
    else:
        out[N - 1] = 1

    return out

const = NonlinearConstraint(con, 0, 1)

bounds = [(0, 1) for i in range(N+2)]

solution = differential_evolution(f, bounds, workers=-1, constraints=const)


But it doesn't work. Some values in x are outside the bounds (< 0, how???) and it ignores the constraint x[i]<=x[i+1]. I think I completely misunderstand how the NonlinearConstraint works. I would appreciate any help!

Why not just have your function return a large value if it finds any x[i] > x[i+1] or x[i]<0? Perhaps with a gradient pointing towards more fertile ground.

Thank you for your response! I tried this option before, but the differential_evolution algorithm failed to locate the any other minimum in that scenario (the minimum value was this high value for x[i] > x[i+1]). When I used the x0 initial configuration, it was unable to move to any other minimum configuration.

I didn't try your last suggestion about the gradient. I can't imagine how the function of x could indicate a minimum if x[i] <= x[i+1], or a maximum if x[i] > x[i+1].
Could you please provide some examples to help me understand better?

Barrier functions like -log(x) or -x*log(x) or in this case -log(x[i+1]-x[i]) can enforce positivity of x smoothly or in your case monotonicity at the expense of bad things happening if x == 0 exactly.  Be sure to start from valid initial values of x.

Not reproducible without f.

The NonlinearConstraint function expects a single value or an array of values, representing the constraint violations. Your con function should return an array where each element corresponds to the difference x[i+1] - x[i]. If this difference is positive (or zero), the constraint is satisfied; otherwise, it's violated.Currently, you're using a single NonlinearConstraint to represent multiple inequalities. Instead, define each constraint individually.  This allows the solver to handle them more effectively. differential_evolution is a global optimization method, it might not be the most suitable for your problem given the constraints. Consider using trust-constr or SLSQP, which are better suited for handling inequality constraints.
    #from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint
import numpy as np

N = ...  # Number of x variables

def objective(x):
    # ... your objective function F(x1, x2, ..., xn, a, b)
    pass

# Individual constraints (one for each x[i] <= x[i+1])
constraints = [NonlinearConstraint(lambda x, i=i: x[i+1] - x[i], 0, np.inf) for i in range(N-1)]

# Bounds for x and other parameters (a, b)
bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in range(N)] + [(0, 1), (0, 1)]  # Assume a and b are the last two elements

# Initial guess for x, a, and b
x0 = np.linspace(0, 1, N)  # Or a better guess if you have one
x0 = np.append(x0, [0.5, 0.5])  # Initial values for a and b

result = minimize(objective, x0, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints, method='SLSQP') 
# or method='trust-constr'

# Optimal solution
if result.success:
    optimal_x = result.x[:N]
    optimal_params = result.x[N:]  # a and b
    print("Optimal x:", optimal_x)
    print("Optimal parameters (a, b):", optimal_params)
else:
    print("Optimization failed:", result.message)

I hope it works!

"Currently, you're using a single NonlinearConstraint to represent multiple inequalities. Instead, define each constraint individually. This allows the solver to handle them more effectively." How do you know? What's your basis for saying this? NonlinearConstraint supports vector valued constraints through VectorFunction - why would breaking it up into multiple scalar functions be helpful?

Thank you for your response! I didn't expect that we needed to differentiate between x[i+1] and x[i]. Here is a working example with another version of the code:
def con(x):
out = np.zeros(N-1)
for i in range(N - 1):
    out[i] = x[i+1] - x[i]

return out

const = NonlinearConstraint(con, 0, 1)
